# Are ASP.NET MVC routes cached?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I added a route to my asp.net mvc application to handle some json requests I need to do.  This works great on my development pc, however when I installed in QA, the route isn't working at all.  I tried to physically type in the address and get a "Bad Request".  Can anyone assist with this?  I have restarted IIS to try to clear any cache but still no luck.  First time, I've seen this as I've made several changes to routes before.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "FsrProblemTypesByEquipment",
            "Fsr/ProblemTypesByEquipment/{equipmentID}",
            new {controller = "Fsr", action = "ProblemTypesByEquipment", equipmentID = ""});
```

Comment: Silly question, but is ASP.NET MVC v1 and .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on your QA server?

Comment: yes, this website has been running since january

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still get a "bad request" if you take out the new route entry, but use the same test URL?  If it is really a problem with your routing table, then your catchall route should get the request.

My guess is that the request is never getting to your routing table; IIS is catching the request before it gets passed to your application.  If that is true, then it is a configuration problem in IIS, or IIS is unhappy with the construction of the URL for some reason.

See this forum post for more information:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1458130/3343674.aspx

Comment: yes, still get bad request.  this is strange because i have several other routes like this and several other json requests that all work the same way

Comment: well, it looks like the problem is the equipment id had an * (asterisk) in it.  once i changed that to a - it started working fine